# "Type Mismatch In Expression", all data types are the same (Access2013)

Tags: ms-access, type-mismatch

Still fairly new at access (self taught), I'm building the foundations of a database I will be using for the next year.

I had a form that worked correctly however once I closed the form then tried to open it again I get an error saying "Type mismatch in expression". All of the datatypes are the same (Short Text) so I don't understand where the error is coming from.

The ID and IDFK are auto number fields. I've also tried linking IDFK to Month_Week.ID and still get the same error.

```
SELECT Month_Week.Month_Week, 
[Idle Times DS16].[Rep1Idle], 
[Idle Times DS16].[Rep2Idle], 
[Idle Times DS16].[Rep3Idle], 
[Idle Times DS16].[Rep4Idle], 
[Idle Times DS16].[Rep5Idle], 
[Idle Times DS16].[Rep6Idle], 
[Idle Times DS16].[Rep7Idle]

FROM [Idle Times DS16] 
INNER JOIN Month_Week 
ON [Idle Times DS16].IDFK = Month_Week.ID;
```

Comment: Have you confirmed the error results from that query instead of some other expression elsewhere in the form?  If you test the query in isolation as a new query in the Access query designer, do you still get that error?

Comment: Yes, I copied the SQL and pasted it into a new blank query and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: OK.  Can you share a copy of the db?  If it contains other stuff you can't share, create a new db and import those 2 tables into it.

Comment: Good.  This query runs without error using that copy of your db: `SELECT * FROM [Idle Times DS16] INNER JOIN Month_Week ON [Idle Times DS16].IDFK = Month_Week.ID;`

Comment: However, the db also contains a query named `TEST`, and that one triggers the mismatch error due to its join condition: `FROM [Idle Times DS16] INNER JOIN Month_Week ON [Idle Times DS16].[IDFK] = Month_Week.[Month_Week]`  And that happens because `[Idle Times DS16].[IDFK]` is numeric but `Month_Week.[Month_Week]` is text datatype --- which is definitely a datatype mismatch.  Sorry, I don't understand what problem you're trying to solve.  :-(

Comment: That actually makes sense. My main error has been opening the forms named DS16 Idle Times & DS17 Idle Times. For some reason that's where I'm getting the error and I think the issues you stated (text to numeric) is what is causing my issue.

Comment: You don't sound quite convinced.  The Record Source queries for both those forms attempt to join `IDFK` (numeric) with `Month_Week` (text), so naturally both throw type mismatch errors.

Comment: I think I'm building my relationships incorrectly. I am going to try adding another field to my tables that I can use that field to link the tables.

Comment: I added the expression you gave in your first reply to the query linked to the form and it got rid of the mismatch error however it's asking for parameter values now, if I click ok through all the messages it will at least allow me to open the form, which I can work with for now (at least until I am able to take a class on access)